# Can a CLOB column containing objects be sorted?

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, clob, querying

I have a column type CLOB that stores an array of objects containing the following structure:

{"id": number, "name": string}

Then suppose we have the following column of CLOB records:

1. [{"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}, {"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}]
2. [{"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}]
3. [{"id": 4, "nombre": "intelectual"}, {"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}]

and so several records that its array in the CLOB column contains at least one object with id and name; then suppose that I have the previous records, is it possible to sort that column by the name property of each first object of each record? example of expected result

1. [{"id": 16, "name": "auditiva"}]
2. [{"id": 21, "name": "fisica"}, {"id": 16, "name": "auditiva"}]
3. [{"id": 4, "name": "intelectual"}, {"id": 21, "name": "fisica"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `JSON_VALUE` function in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name 
ORDER BY JSON_VALUE(value, '$[0].nombre');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value CLOB CHECK (value IS JSON)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO table_name (value)
  SELECT '[{"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}, {"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}]' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '[{"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}]' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '[{"id": 4, "nombre": "intelectual"}, {"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}]' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| [{"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}] |
| [{"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}, {"id": 16, "nombre": "auditiva"}] |
| [{"id": 4, "nombre": "intelectual"}, {"id": 21, "nombre": "fisica"}] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FLdPv9qX)